# Enabling .htaccess file to rewrite path (not working)

Tags: apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All the tutorials tell me to edit the: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but this file doesn't exist for me. Within this file I would have to edit the:

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> AllowOverride None
> #AllowOverride All
> #AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=All, MultiViews        
> Order allow,deny
> allow from all </Directory>
> ```

What should the file look like and should I create it myself?

Aslo I do have a `000-default.conf` file but the above 'code' isn't in there either.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For apache version 2.4 and later, you have to go to

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

You have to edit that file (you should have root permission). Change directory text like this;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now restart apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Can you please explain what this does? How does this tie in with the .htaccess? My .htaccess in not getting read at all.

Comment: The important line here is `AllowOverride All`, this means all settings can be set (overridden) in `.htaccess` files. See docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: If it is still not working try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and then `sudo service apache2 restart`, this worked for me.

Comment: This is bad advice for an accepted and highly voted answer. You are changing the main config file, so each time you upgrade your system you have to manually fix the diff. It's better to override the config elsewhere. Also, as of Apache 2.4, the DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html` not `/var/www`.

Answer (score 36):

As of Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache 2.4), the default DocumentRoot was changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html`.

Firstly enable a2enmod and restart Apache.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then edit the `000-default.conf` file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and add these lines at the end

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Finally, restart Apache for the configuration to take effect.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This solution works for me because, I need to enable mod_rewrite first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This really worked for apache 2.4. Saved my day. Even after editing maing apache2.conf .htaccess didn't work but doing this way it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, instead, using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: For Ubuntu; this is the solution that works!

Comment: when i was trying to find a reason for why .htaccess files aren't working at all this directory directive snippet saved the day.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to repeat the same configurtion at each upgrade / update

**The best way is :**

*Edit or create a config file*

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/httpd.conf`

*Add*

`<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

*Enable the config file*

`sudo a2enconf httpd`

*Restart or reload Apache*

`sudo service apache2 restart`

*or*

`sudo service apache2 reload`

**It's done!**